suppress R library messages
No matter what I do, the messages from loading logbin cannot be stopped.
sink(nullfile())
  suppressMessages(
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(
      capture.output(
        library('logbin'),
        file = nullfile()
      )
    )
  )
sink()

# package is loaded lazily so we need to use it
data = data.frame(y=0:1,x=0:1)
m = logbin(y~x,data=data)

Is there any way to suppress these messages?

I downvoted for the choice of rude words and edited the question accordingly. There is no need to use those (on this platform).

This is not a question of humor.

Please see this SE Meta post regarding the use of expletives.

99 times out of 100 the warning may not be necessary.  But on that odd occasion, you will be glad you can see it.  And cursing yourself - ligitimately - when you can't.

The package-loading messages might go away if the package maintainers explicitly listed imports in the NAMESPACE file.  You might try opening an issue ...

Just move suppress... to function call:
library(logbin)
data = data.frame(y=0:1,x=0:1)
m = suppressPackageStartupMessages(suppressWarnings(logbin(y~x,data=data)))
m
#> 
#> Call:  logbin(formula = y ~ x, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            x  
#>      -36.84        36.84  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 1 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       2.773 
#> Residual Deviance: 6.358e-07     AIC: 4

Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0
